# What are some good ways to verify data integrity for home use with Windows?

Tags: backup, hard-drive, disk-image, incremental-backup

I currently make backups of my family pictures from my hard drive to an external drive and archive this every few months on a safe location. How can I guarantee that the file on my external drive and/or hard disk are not corrupted every time i make a backup (without having to check whether the pictures are still OK everytime)?

Answer (score 1):

EEAA's answer is good but I would recommend MD5 hashes, because it would be faster and in this case you don't care about security.

Here's a Powershell command that you can use to generate a list of hashes:

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path (Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\files\*.*" -Recurse) | Export-CSV C:\Temp\Hashlist.csv
```

Run that on both your source directory and your backup directory, and then compare the lists.  Note that the Get-FileHash cmdlet is only available in Powershell 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to run an sha2 hash over all of the files in each location and compare the output. Each file's SHA2 should match. If it doesn't, you don't have a good backup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an rsync implementation to sync directories but with the `--dry-run` flag set. This will flag any files that don't match and need to be synced.

Answer (score 0):

As already was meantioned, you may use some hashing utility to check file's integrity, but it will not save/recover files itself.
You may use for hashing:
[DirHash](https://idrassi.github.io/DirHash/),
[Hash-it](http://www.trishtech.com/hash-it/),
[QuickHash](http://quickhash-gui.org/) or even Microsoft's solution [PsFCIV](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-File-Checksum-e57dcd67)

If you want not to just checking for integrity but also want ability to recover data in case if source (original) files and backuped get corrupted then you may want to use  [par2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) utility that keep additional extra information that allow you to recover even broken files. You can use Windows version of [par2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) utility that called [MultiPar](https://multipar.eu/download/)

You can use also [PureSync](https://www.jumpingbytes.com/en/puresync/features/backup/) for backup purpose and set
`Compare methods` in settings to `By contents (compare binary)`.
Every time you using [PureSync](https://www.jumpingbytes.com/en/puresync/features/backup/) it will compare source and destination directories by content(which actually will be pretty slow since PC will need reread all files to be able to test file's integrity).

You can create [par2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) archives at original destination and sync it with [PureSync](https://www.jumpingbytes.com/en/puresync/features/backup/) to backup drive.